# How to make EclipseLink MOXy ignore AspectJ fields?

Tags: eclipselink, aspectj, moxy

## How do I make a bytecode-only Field be @XmlTransient?

When a class is woven by AspectJ, its bytecode (but **not** its source code) receives an extra injected static field:

```
private static final org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint$StaticPart ajc$tjp_0;
```

This extra field is not treated as XmlTransient by  MOXy, and causes an Exception  when trying to create a JAXBContext:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Exception Description: The class org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl$StaticPartImpl requires a zero argument constructor or a specified factory method.  Note that non-static inner classes do not have zero argument constructors and are not supported.
- with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The class org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl$StaticPartImpl requires a zero argument constructor or a specified factory method.  Note that non-static inner classes do not have zero argument constructors and are not supported.]
```

## Possible solutions

According to the [EclipseLink MOXy example](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/ExternalizedMetadata), it seems that I should be able to make this field `@XmlTransient` by creating a file called `eclipselink-oxm.xml` with the content below, and place the file within the directory `src/main/resources/META-INF`. However, this does not work.

How should I proceed here?

### eclipselink-oxm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xml-bindings
        xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        version="${eclipselink.version}">
      <java-types>
        <java-type name="se.mithlond.services.organisation.model.address.CategorizedAddress">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-transient java-attribute="ajc$tjp_0"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <!--java-type name="org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl$StaticPartImpl" xml-transient="true" />
        <java-type name="org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl" xml-transient="true" / -->
      </java-types>
   </xml-bindings>
```

Comment: ... and, of course, the simplest solutions are frequently the best ones. Simply remove any trace of the `AspectJ`-created class from the `JAXBContext.newInstance(...)` method call and the problem disappears.

Comment: Please write an answer for your own question and accept it after a few days so as to close this question. Alternatively, delete the question - your choice. :-)

Comment: This seems like a good question. Let's keep it as it may have value to other people.